# How to determine if element is of a certain component type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to use the ReactIs library to determine if an element is of a certain type of component.  Here is my code:

```
React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
  if (ReactIs.typeOf(child) === ReactIs.typeOf(MyComponent)) {
      // Do something
  }
});
```

This does not work as expected, however.  It never makes it in my IF block.

How can I determine if an element is of a certain component type?

Comment: have you tried `child.type === MyComponent`?

Comment: is it inside unit tests?

Comment: p.s. it looks like the `ReactIs` library has a method `isValidElementType` ... did you try it?

Comment: @Errorname `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'symbol | undefined' and 'typeof MyComponent' have no overlap`.

Comment: @sadrzadehsina That works! If you add your comment as an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: @im1dermike already added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the right way for checking whether a react component is a specific type or not is the below one.

```
React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
  if (child.type === MyComponent) {
      // Do something
  }
});
```

You missed a closing `)` too, at the end of your if statement.

```
if (ReactIs.typeOf(child) === ReactIs.typeOf(MyComponent)) {
  ...
}
```